# Jquery vertical menu collapses with Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

Im using the menu as it is from - http://cssmenumaker.com/builder/1501457. This works like a Jquery Accordion, keeping only one panel open at a time.
When a main menu is expanded and I click on a submenu, it navigates to that page, but the Main menu collapses with the page refresh. How can I keep it fixed.

Using it in Asp.Net Master page.

The css and jquery are in the link

Answer (score 3):

The menu provided on this page is using javascript to dynamically update the menu state.

This means that your html page is stateful and the issue arise because you then need to correctly handle the transfer of state between your client and server code.

You then have three alternative solutions:

1. transfer your client application state (current menu) to your asp backend and regenerate the new page based on this state
2. transer your application state to your asp backend and send it back to the client browser and make sure this state is then reapplied by the client (use javascript)
3. only request the new data to your asp backend and render the new page content in client javascript

This issue might also be the symptom that you are not using the right tool for building your menu. You are indeed mixing server and client side rendering and it feels from your question that you might be better off with a complete server side rendering.

Comment: Could you plz guide further with sample with the first option

Comment: This menu object is rendered in large part by a client side javascript. This effectively makes solution 1) difficult to implement and maintain. I would advise to go for the alternative 2) and roundtrip the menu state from the browser to the server and then back to browser in the new page as a javascript object inserted within the html page. This will enable you to reapply the required state on the client side. For example you could use jQuery to simulate the click on the desired menu based on the state provided by the server.

Answer (score 1):

Add the class active in the li of your current menu, and add style="display: block;" to the child ul element you want to show as open.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub active'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul style="display: block;">
         <li><a href='#'><span>Widgets</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Menus</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Location</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Put active and display:block for 'Products'. It works only for the Products menu now. The Company menu collapses as before. So I did display block for that too. Now both main menus display expanded at page load, and also, as the product it active, it is always expanded even when showing some other pages

Comment: Hmm, I think I wasn't clear enough. I suggested it as a way to display the current submenu open because you are reloading the page. That means that you have somehow (server side or client side) to add these the class active to the correct li every time you reload the page and the style block to the child ul of it.

So you have to find a way to add these everytime the page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use accordion. because accordion opens only one tab open in same time. try to use slideDwon Jquery